# What is carved into Toko's leg?

Tags: danganronpa

DanganRonpa: Ultra Despair Girls came out today in Europe and there's something I noticed about the 3D model of Toko Fukawa.

> A.K.A Genocider Jack

[image]

There's something cut into her leg. I'm not sure that picture is an official model from the game, but I have definitely seen it while playing (screenshot below):

[image]

In the other games, we mostly see her waist-up - or in an uncut skirt, so I've never noticed it before:

[image: DR]

**What has she got carved into her leg?**

I've only been playing the games - is there another source that describes how it got there?

Comment: looks like a tally marking to me, using the five-stroke kanji.

Comment: It's tally marks of how many people Genocider Syo killed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mark seen on Genocider Syo is the Japanese Kanji 正

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A3) has a page on this character explaining its use as a tally mark by the Japanese.

Genocider Syo uses the tally to count the amount of victims she has killed. There is also a small section on this on the [Wikia](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Jack).

Since each one represents 5 kills, you can see she has killed quite a few!

[image: Close up of the Genocider Syo's leg]